# JavaScript string concatenation speed

Tags: javascript, string

Can someone explain this one to me:

http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation-1/2

If you're lazy, I tested A) vs B):

A)

```
var innerHTML = "";

items.forEach(function(item) {
    innerHTML += item;
});
```

B)

```
var innerHTML = items.join("");
```

Where `items` for both tests is the same 500-element array of strings, with each string being random and between 100 and 400 characters in length.

A) ends up being 10x faster. How can this be--I always thought concatenating using `join("")` was an optimization trick. Is there something flawed with my tests?

Comment: Unless you're joining very large number of strings (very large is browser dependent), `Array.Join` is slower then `+`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `join("")` was an optimization trick for composing large strings on IE6 to avoid `O(n**2)` buffer copies.  It was never expected to be a huge performance win for composing small strings since the `O(n**2)` only really dominates the overhead of an array for largish n.

Modern interpreters get around this by using "dependent strings".  See this [mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616910) for an explanation of dependent strings and some of the advantages and drawbacks.

Basically, modern interpreters knows about a number of different kinds of strings:

1. An array of characters
2. A slice (substring) of another string
3. A concatenation of two other strings

This makes concatenation and substring O(1) at the cost of sometimes keeping too much of a substringed buffer alive resulting in inefficiency or complexity in the garbage collector.

Some modern interpreters have played around with the idea of further decomposing (1) into byte[]s for ASCII only strings, and arrays of uint16s when a string contains a UTF-16 code unit that can't fit into one byte.  But I don't know if that idea is actually in any interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Here the author of Lua programming language [explains the buffer overhead](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html) that @Mike Samuel is telling about. The examples are in Lua, but the issue is the same in JavaScript.