# efficiently concatenate array of strings

Tags: arrays, ocaml, string-concatenation

The OCaml standard library provides the function `String.concat`

https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html

> `val concat : string -> string list -> string`
>
> `String.concat sep sl` concatenates the list of strings `sl`, inserting the separator string
>   `sep` between each.

Presumably this function exists to make easier to concatenate many strings together in time/space linear in the length of the strings.

Does similar functionality exist for arrays? In particular, is there a way to efficiently concatenate an array of strings together without either 1) writing a C extension and building a tricky intermediate structure or 
 2) effectively calling `String.concat "" (Array.to_list arr))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best is to write your own `concat` function imitating `String.concat`.  If you want something shorter, use a buffer to accumulate the result of your result (`Array.iter (Buffer.add_string b) arr`) — do not do repeated concatenations which will generate too many allocations.

Comment: Could you expand on the "too many allocations" comment? When compiled to JavaScript (and run on V8), concatenation is still faster than `Buffer.add_string` (see the updated benchmark link in my answer). This doesn't necessarily translate to OCaml of course, but it makes it non-obvious to me that "too many allocations" is a problem. Especially since OCaml's GC ought to be tuned for many allocations due to its emphasis on immutability.

Comment: Say that the strings in your array have lengths n₁, n₂,..., nₖ.  Concatenating recursively will create a string of length n₁+n₂, then n₁+n₂+n₃, n₁+n₂+n₃+n₄,... That depends on the string representation in the language of course — if represented using, say, ropes then concatenation is really fast (O(1)).  Javascript seems to be using "dependent strings" which seems to be another name for ropes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551918/javascript-string-concatenation-speed  (There is a Rope module for OCaml BTW.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing it, like the unsafe_blit approach `String.concat` is using, but a simple fold is at least an improvement over option 2:

```
Array.fold_left (fun acc s -> acc ^ s) "" arr
```

[Reason/BuckleScript benchmark](https://rebench.github.io/?rebench-data=NoIgNgpgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDAgk1A6ASwDsCoAKARgAYaAaGAZygWIHMB9AewDN3ioAlAG4AOkUixIRVlAAWGbLhR5unMABN2kbuTJwAxvvoMBGAHzxDMANQwAyszZ4pM2WRP0q9RMhTCQtMCgACwB4NAwAEYKAEIArtzcEAh4+ggQcFAQZC5ywmI+qDAAPhY4voRZCGTxicl4cOqaTCzSZJECAiAAuoEgAMxhElGxCUkpaRlZZFT5RIVopYoVpMk1Y-WNzY5tHV29oABMYQslZUoqapraugZGjKboFnc2tgz0IiCf-gcgFCdKM7LfBQThaAhMIEOVqsVKcIj6TJkT7fIQ9brdIA)

Comment: Err ... in this case the efficiency of `String.concat` is what I'm trying to duplicate. The `blit` functionality is `Bytes` is certainly useful though ... and you might be able to cobble together an efficient implementation for arrays of strings ...